# Should I inject Firebase instances?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, analytics

I added firebase analytics to my project and I'm using analytics in every use case. So in every file, I need to create a firebase analytics instance. like
`FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;`.

So I was thinking what if I use getIt and inject the instance wherever I need in that case only one instance will be created. like  `getIt.registerSingleton(FirebaseAnalytics.instance);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting the `FirebaseAnalytics` directly, use a Wrapper and inject that, like this.

Define your Wrapper first:

```dart
class Analytics {
  Analytics(this.firebaseAnalytics);

  final FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;

  void logEvent(String eventName, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    // log any analytics here.
  }
}
```

Create your wrapper.

```dart
final analytics = Analytics(FirebaseAnalytics.instance);
```

Inject your wrapper (you can use any service injector).

```dart
getIt.registerSingleton(analytics);
```

Then you can retrieve your dependency from any Widget/Bloc.

Why?

Imagine later you want to add or switch another Analytic provider, we'll just need to modify your wrapper instead of updating all of your widgets.

This will also help for testing, you will be able to mock your Wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to inject them using a dependency manager package, the Firebase services's `instance` getter is implemented like this:

```
   /// Returns an instance using the default [FirebaseApp].
  static FirebaseAuth get instance {
    FirebaseApp defaultAppInstance = Firebase.app();

    return FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: defaultAppInstance);
  }

  /// Returns an instance using a specified [FirebaseApp].
  /// Note that persistence can only be used on Web and is not supported on other platforms.
  factory FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(
      {required FirebaseApp app, Persistence? persistence}) {
    return _firebaseAuthInstances.putIfAbsent(app.name, () {
      return FirebaseAuth._(app: app, persistence: persistence);
    });
  }
```

so calling multiple `instance` getters across your entire app will not register it every time, it will register it only the first time with the `putIfAbsent`, after that it will directly return that instance.